# pass PHP variable to NSString in xcode

Tags: php, iphone, xcode

Is it possible to store a PHP variable value in NSString?

getvariable.php

```
<?php
$variable = 6;
?>
```

Note: I am not interested in just using UIWebview to just visit getvariable.php and echo $getvariable. I need to store this variable in NSString.

How can I do it? is it through NSURLRequest, NSURLConnection??

Comment: PHP and Obj-C cannot simply "store" each other's variables. They need to communicate likely through an HTTP request. For that, you need to *output* the PHP variable, which then is simply text, which can be parsed and stored using Obj-C like any other HTTP response data.

Comment: That is right. I am parsing XML in my app too through http requests. I just need to know how to do this simple http request in order to get the value and store it in NSString.

Answer (score 1):

I got it.

In variable.php

```
<?php
$var = 11;
echo $var;
?>
```

in my xcode class.m

```
NSString * url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://website.com/variable.php"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url ]];
NSString * serverOutput= [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSLog(@"php variable is %@,serverOutput"); // it will print 11;
```

Comment: I know this is a very old question, but I have a quick question. How would could I pass an NSString to a PHP variable?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass variable from PHP to Objective c, or to any other client application for that matter,
You will need to create a layer XML or RESTful interface to get that variable

For example you could update your php to the following (simple text, of JSON if you want)

```
<?php
echo ("Variable:6");
?>
```

Then in xCode do the following

```
NSString *strContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:@"YourUrl/getvariable.php"];
//Then get the var
NSString *strVariable = [strContent substringFromIndex:
               [strContent rangeOfString:@":"].location];
```

This is a simple synchronous text request, if you want you can change it to JSON and to asynchronous